# Twitter API v2 integration with laravel 8 usign atymic

Tags: twitter, laravel-8, twitter-api-v2

I am trying to use the Twitter API v2, but every time I do run on the site, I get an error:

> Atymic\Twitter\Exception\Request\UnauthorizedRequestException
> A request error occurred. Client error: `GET https://api.twitter.com/2/tweets/search/recent?place.fields=country%2Cname&tweet.fields=author_id%2Cgeo&expansions=author_id%2Cin_reply_to_user_id&query=a` resulted in a `401 Unauthorized` response: { "title": "Unauthorized", "type": "about:blank", "status": 401, "detail": "Unauthorized" }

Here is the responsible controller.

Mediacontroller:

```
<?php

namespace App\Http\Controllers;

use Illuminate\Http\Request;
use Atymic\Twitter\Twitter as TwitterContract;
use Illuminate\Http\JsonResponse;
use Twitter;


class mediacontroller extends Controller
{


public function searchRecent(string $query): JsonResponse
{
    $params = [
        'place.fields' => 'country,name',
        'tweet.fields' => 'author_id,geo',
        'expansions' => 'author_id,in_reply_to_user_id',
        TwitterContract::KEY_RESPONSE_FORMAT => TwitterContract::RESPONSE_FORMAT_JSON,
    ];

    return JsonResponse::fromJsonString(Twitter::searchRecent($query, $params));
}

}
```

And here is the Routing

```
Route::get('media/{query}',[mediacontroller::class,'searchRecent']);
```

And when run, the out come is, you can head over and test it yourself its [https://mytry.studio/media/](https://mytry.studio/media/1540697420027383808). what follows after the media/ is the query.

[image]

The reference of all the code is from the atymic documentation on github

[atymic github documentation](https://github.com/atymic/twitter)

Comment: was u fix this error?

Comment: never got an answer untill today, have it in archived projects